# Communicating errors generated in model to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the correct way to propagate errors generated in a model to the user?

For example, I have a `Reminder` model with a time associated. I also have a static method `create_new` as follows:

```
def self.create_new date_string, time_string
    Reminder.new DateTime.parse(#{date_string} #{time_string})
end
```

In the controller, I'm calling this method to create a new reminder. The form view and controller are straightforward.
When the user has a typo in his time field (ie: 112:45 instead of 11:45), `parse` will raise an error. 
What's the best way to notify an the user of the location of the typo in the form? I'd like to avoid using javascript on the client side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller:

```
def action
  r = create_new params
  -- do stuff
rescue StandardError => e
  flash.now[:error] = e.message
end
```

In your view you can then just render the output of flash.now[:error] to display the errors if any.
I use the flash variable also for all validation messages and what not when updating models or when creation fails.

source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Comment: I have the same code in both update & create. Is there a way to get around having to do the error correction twice?

Comment: Not unless you make either a global rescue on your ApplicationsController, make your custom code more generic or prevent bad data being injected using javascript.  You can add a rescue in your function to catch all and return a default value instead so that you at elast have a reminder set for let's say the next hour by default.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend handling this in the Reminder model with validations. You can either write your own custom validator as explained [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) or use an existing gem like [validates_timeliness](https://github.com/johncarney/validates_timeliness).

This allows you to follow Rails' convention over configuration methodology and avoid writing custom create methods on the model or littering your controller code with rescue blocks.

Your controller action would then become

```
def create
  @reminder = Reminder.new(reminder_params)
  if @reminder.save
    # redirect or whatever
  else
    flash.now[:error] = @reminder.errors.full_messages
  end
end
```

The same can then be performed in the `update` action. Hope this helps.

Comment: In this case, I don't see how to implement it as you suggested. I have a `date` and `time` field in my form, which is merged in a `datetime` field in the model. The error is created during parsing, before the data is injected in the model, so before validation. Am I missing something?

Comment: Right, I'm saying _not to_ parse it using your own `create_new` method.  Instead, create it as you would any other Rails model and let the validation handle it (e.g. `Reminder.new my_datetime_column: "#{params[:date]} #{params[:time]}"`)

Comment: You're right, that seems to be the best solution. Right now I don't want to touch the model, so I'm going to go with @NekoNova 's solution. But I won't make the same mistake again in the future!